# Holidays for close relatives assistance in Austria

Tags: austria, health-care, holidays

If one close relative (he is resident in Italy) had suffered a stroke, do the local laws in Austria allow to take holidays to take care of him?

I'm resident in Austria and I work there since less than one year. I'm an Italian citizen.

Comment: Can you provide additional information on the specific. Are you residing in Austria? What is your status there?

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of an e-card in this question.

Comment: I don't see how this is an expat-specific question? The local laws would surely apply whether you're a local or an expat no? Putting on hold for more details for now.

Comment: I think this point should be clarified in the meta section.. since as local people would have no problem at reading in their native language the documentation about any topic.. As well as any native could speak with the dozen of friend, relatives and colleagues more old than him and ask for information. Try to find as many questions as you can and wonder if a native would probably already know (or find easily) the answer. And also what is the benefit, the pro of closing the question? Of course this is my opinion. For me the whole section is for people who experiment similar problems

Comment: @DavidSegonds: I've edited the question

Comment: @MarkMayo It may affect visa.  Similar situation for: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/259/holidays-in-us-for-close-relatives-funeral-in-eu?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

According to the Lexology overview of [employment & labour law in Austria](http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=02d21736-d503-466d-9d14-3d662f6aa169),

> Employees may take up to two weeks of paid time off per year in order to provide medical care to a close relative (e.g., spouse, civil partner or child).
>
> Employees can request family care leave/part-time employment in order to look after an ill family member. Family care leave/part-time employment can be used only to care for a close family member who is receiving a certain level of Austrian care allowance (known as ‘pflegegeld’).

The Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development [report on leave entitlements](https://www.oecd.org/els/soc/PF2_3_Additional_leave_entitlements_of_working_parents.pdf) notes that, in Austria, employees may be allowed:

- Paid leave to care for a child under age 12: 2 weeks per year (100% of earnings);
- Paid leave to care for dependants other than children: 1 week per year (100% of earnings);
- Unpaid leave to care for terminally ill family members or seriously ill children; 6 months (extendable to 9 months) per episode.

Thus, employers are not required to grant leave to attend to an uncle to whom you're close, but is not an immediate, dependant family member. You may be given permission for a paid or unpaid absence, but there is not a legal or regulatory requirement.