# Are there alternatives to a cheque for "caution" (deposit) when renting as a new arrival in France?

Tags: france, banking, rental

I've been in France a few days now, and I'm looking to rent somewhere (hotels etc being a little expensive for the long term). Having spoken with a few agents, they all *seem* to want a Euro denominated cheque for the caution (deposit).

Now, the problem is that I don't have a French bank account, so I don't have a euro cheque book with which to write a caution cheque.

We've a good question on [How to open bank account in France if I don't have address of residence yet](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-to-open-bank-account-in-france-if-i-dont-have-address-of-residence-yet), but sadly it doesn't have any simple answers on how to resolve the catch-22 that is opening a bank account without a permanent address, and without the chequebook to get one.

So, what I'm wondering is - are there any alternative ways of supplying the caution money other than a cheque, which is likely to be accepted? A cheque in another currency perhaps? (I have cheque books in GBP Sterling and USD Dollars for example). Euro bank transfer somewhere secure? Euro cash with appropriate receipts? Anything else?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that the cheque is important. I remember, as far as I can, always using cheques because it is the most common means of payment for large sums in France.

While using cash is a bit weird because the amount is large, I think a wire would be fine. The last time I started to rent an apartment I payed the first rent (along with the deposit) with a cheque and all the following rents with a wire.

Anyway most likely you will have to pay three things at the same time: the deposit, the first rent and the agency fee (if you go through an agency). That represents a lot of money and if you prove your payment, I think the agency will not have any problem (but ask them before as a wire takes time to be processed).

Comment: In the end, I found somewhere willing to take two month's rent up front, then accept a caution cheque a month later, but not everywhere was willing to offer that